# ImageLevel change every 100ms on an object in a custom array adapter

Tags: android, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have an Activity which uses a fragment. The fragment contains a custom array adapter to display over 190 elements.

Each element contains among other views, an `ImageView` for which I defined an Level list drawable resource containing 14 images
 - 0 -> Play
 - 1-12 -> Spinning States
 - 13 -> Stop

When the user clicks the `ImageView`, the state is changed from 0->1 and an IntetnService is started to perform a download in background. Once the download is finalized, the `IntentService` sends a `LocalBroadcastMessage`. The activity holding the fragment has a receiver which calls a method in the fragment to update the `ArrayAdapter`. The update is done by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter`. When the views are recreated, the state of `ImageView` is changed to 13. To achieve this, I store in a Singleton the id of the object associated with the element from the `ArrayAdapter` for which the user clicked the `ImageView`. In the `getView()` method, if the layout for the object stored is recreated, the image level of the `ImageView` is set to 13. After the media file previously downloaded has finished playing, another LocalBroadcastMessage and the entire process is triggered again to change the image level to 0.

I want to be implement a mechanism to cycle the state of the `ImageView` while the `IntentService` is running from 1 to 12 every 100ms. This has to be done only for the element in the `ArrayAdapter` for which the user clicked the `ImageView`. The image has to be spinning when the user scrolls away from the element and then scrolls back, if the `IntentService` is not yet finished.

I tried doing this by starting an `AsyncTask`, every time the user clicks the `ImageView` and the image level is changed from 0->1. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter`from the `onProgressUpdate()` method was a bad idea because the entire was refreshed to often.

Can anyone help me with some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem last night

The final implementation uses an `AsyncTask` that calls `onProgressUpdate()` every 100ms, updating the image level in a singleton class.

When the `ImageView` is clicked, I store in a global variable in the fragment class, the reference to this view and attached the current object from the custom `ArrayAdapter` using `setTag()`.

Every time the `getView()` method returns a recycled view, I check if the `ImageView` contains the object being processed in it's tag. If it does, I set it to `null`.

If the `AsyncTask` is running, in `onProgressUpdate()` I check if the global variable where I store the `ImageView` contains as tag the object currently processed. If it contains then I update the image, otherwise not.